# Changing the color of active nav-item and displays the page relative to the navbar item

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

I've tried a lot of things but can't change the background color of a active nav-item and also display the page relative to the navbar item.

**Note:** The below jQuery code changes the background color of navbar list item, but the moment I click on the page it gets back to the default color. If I add 'e.preventDefault()' it changes correctly the nav-item background color, but doesn't display the page relative to the navbar item.

HTML (EJS file)

```
 <div class="navbar-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-nav > .aMenuActive {
    background-color: var(--main-pink-color);
}
```

JQuery

```
// aMenuActive -> Add class to clicked li
$('ul.navbar-nav > li').click(function (e) {    
    console.log("log...clicked menu",);
    $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('aMenuActive');
    $(this).addClass('aMenuActive');
    //e.preventDefault(); // -> works but does not send to link
});
```

```js
$('ul.navbar-nav > li').click(function (e) {    
    console.log("log...clicked menu",);
    $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('aMenuActive');
    $(this).addClass('aMenuActive');
    //e.preventDefault(); // -> works but does not send to link
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav > .aMenuActive {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Seen this a few times on SO - you're clicking the link which is then *navigating to a new page* thus recreating the page.  You need to add a check on the page load to set the `aMenuActive` based on the current page / or load the page using ajax.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look on how ajax works, I will need that for improving my code. Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to overwrite css property white that predefined in *boostrap.min.css* file. You can find through *Inspect Element*.

Comment: @danielbcarvalho have you been able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

href will trigger the page reload and losing the selection.

You can change background color just by css.

```css
.navbar-nav > .nav-item:focus-within {
  background-color: pink; //var(--main-pink-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-nav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-auto px-lg-2 px-xl-3" href="/index/2">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-auto px-lg-2 px-xl-3 " href="/index/viagens">VIAGENS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-auto px-lg-2 px-xl-3" href="/index/3">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-auto px-lg-2 px-xl-3" href="/index/4">Item 3</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When the page reload it gets back to the default color even changing background color by css. But thanks for the answer, I'll try to restructure my code. I've spent a lot of time in this feature...